# Chrome embed VLC Player couldn't playback MP4

Tags: google-chrome, vlc

I trying to embed vlc player in chrome to playback mp4 video, but with no success.

What I did:

1) Installed VLC player

- sudo apt-get install vlc.

2) Visit chrome://plugins, disabled VLC Multimedia Plug-in, enabled **VLC Multimedia Plugin (compatible Totem 3.0.1)**.

- able to play ogg video but not mp4 video

3) Visit chrome://plugins, disabled VLC Multimedia Plugin (compatible Totem 3.0.1), **enabled VLC Multimedia Plugin**

- plugin not found

How do I get mp4 playback with VLC player for chrome, Firefox is running fine. Can someone give a clue on what's the different between these 2 plugins and why VLC Multimedia plugin without totem won't work on chrome?

Comment: Install ubuntu restricted extras

Answer (score 1):

There no longer is a `VLC Multimedia Plugin`, it's been split off to `Vlc Web Plugin`

So if you're using a ppa see if they have the package. Otherwise it's available in 12.04, package name `browser-plugin-vlc`

What you've been enabling/disabling is the `Totem Mozilla plugin` which encompasses the 2 plugins in screen below that I have greyed out by disabling.

By & large the totem plugin is quite good, may even be better than the vlc one, only experimenting & personal use case would tell.

To fully enable the totem plugin install the `ubuntu-restricted-addons` package or -extras as mentioned.

gstreamer plugins themselves are not used by vlc

If you do end up with this vlc browser plugin you probably should disable any other totem based plugin in chrome

[image]

Comment: Installed ubuntu-restricted-extras, but the issue remains. Any chance to install vlc web plugin with ubuntu 11.10?